# How can I access the url in cypress and change the value of one of the parameters, or just change the value of the url?

Tags: cypress

I have a certain url, and by entering values ​​with parameters I get from in inputs, how can I change the value using cypress in url

```
http://localhost:28080/app/form/54fd3434f? -initial url

http://localhost:28080/app/form/54fd3434f?text_field=Text&text_field2=Text2  -expected url 
after type
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this -

```
cy.url().then(url => {
    cy.visit(url + 'text_field=Text&text_field2=Text2')
});
```

`cy.url()` will yield the current URL as a string. Now add the parameters that you want to add and using `cy.visit()` you can access the new url.

Comment: what if I want to modify cy.url in component test? is there any equal cy.visit syntax in component test?

Comment: @DarrylRN that feels like a seperate question, did you ask it by any chance?